# jQuery validate with AJAX in submitHandler, submits on second click?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm new to AJAX and used the code from this SO answer here [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/capture-all-of-the-forms-data-and-submit-it-to-a-php-script-jquery-ajax-post) to integrate with a form on a WordPress site. It works just fine, but i'm having trouble integrating it with jquery validation

I tried placing the javascript from the page above into the `submitHandler` function below

```
$("#my-form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    **js from other page**
  }
});
```

My form validates on the first click. Then if i type into the input and submit nothing happens, I have to click a second time for the form to submit properly with AJAX. Below is a jsfiddle. Any help is appreciated thanks.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkWjV/) of my code thought it'll log an error to console since form.php isn't linked

Comment: What is `**js from other page**` supposed to be?   Please show enough code to make a concise demo of the problem.  Your OP should not rely on the external links to show all the relevant code.  The jQuery Validate plugin only requires _one_ click unless you've mistakenly wrapped `.validate()` inside a `click` or `submit` handler.  And in your case, you've mistakenly wrapped a `submit` handler inside of the plugin's default `submitHandler`.  Since the plugin's `submitHandler` callback already captures the submit event, your enclosed `submit` handler is redundant.

Answer (score 13):

The job of the submitHandler is to submit the form, not to register a form submit event handler.

The submitHandler is called when the formm submit event is triggered, in your case instead of submitting the form you were registering a submit handler so when the form submit event is triggered for the first time the form is not submitted. when it is fired for the second time first the submit event is processed by the validator then the handler you registered is fired which triggers the ajax request.

In the submitHandler you just have to sent the ajax request there is no need to register the event handler

```
$("#add-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(form);
        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // fire off the request to /form.php

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "forms.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            alert("success awesome");
            $('#add--response').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>');
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });

        // callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Arun I just checked this code and my input value isn't being sent to the form.php file. Going back to the old code with validation works. A few changes in your code are not having var request and function (form) instead of event. Could any of these changes cause my input to not be sent? Thanks

Comment: This ended up working `submitHandler: function (form) {var $form = $(form);` otherwise I get a form is not defined error

Comment: What should be the URL of the url parameter (here it is url:forms.php) if my js code is in a js/custom.js location?

Comment: is .validate() a plugin? I can't find anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `$("#add-form").submit(function(){...})` doesn't submit the form. It binds a handler that says what to do *when* the user submits the form. That's why you have to submit twice: the first time invokes the validate plugin's submit handler, which validates the data and runs your function, and the second time invokes the submit handler that you added the first time.

Don't wrap the code inside `.submit()`, just do it directly in your `submitHandler:` function. Change:

```
var $form = $(this);
```

to:

```
var $form = $(form);
```

You don't need `event.PreventDefault()`, the validate plugin does that for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#add-form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var request;
        // bind to the submit event of our form



        // let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $(form).find("input, select, button, textarea");
        // serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $(form).serialize();

        // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // fire off the request to /form.php

        request = $.ajax({
                url: "forms.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // log a message to the console
                console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                alert("success awesome");
                $('#add--response').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>');
        });

        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // log the error to the console
                console.error(
                    "The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
        });

            // callback handler that will be called regardless
            // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
                // reenable the inputs
                $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });            

    }
});
```