# Label Error in css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a form of textboxes with validation.

It is working fine if we click the save button first time it showing correctly. But once if we fill the text boxes and then remove the text from text boxes it is error message is getting displayed on text boxes. please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fYxb/2/

CSS:

```
#field
{
  margin-left: .5em;
  float: right;
}
#field, label
{
  float:left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}
br
{
  clear: both;
}
input
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  width: 72px;
}
input.error
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label.error
{
  position:fixed;
  Background-image:url("../images/unchecked.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px; 
  margin-left: .3em;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color: #FFEBE8;  
  border: solid 1px red;
  width:210px;
  height:15px;
}
label.valid
{
  position:absolute;
  Background-image:url("../images/checked.gif") ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px; 
  margin-left: .3em;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color:White;
  border:none;
  width:1px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Note that you also might want to look at `serialize()` etc. when you post the form data. For example look at how its is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18265708/3278057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need float left for `#field` and `label`?

```
 #field, label {
     float:left;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: small;
 }
```

If you remove that and also remove position form label *error* and label *valid*:

http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/8SM7f/

Also, you would probably want to fix the mobile number check. Your current:

```
/[789]\d{9}$/
```

Would validate

```
// This as OK
7111111111
// But this would also validate this as OK:
123155551333321212121521251215421212487884655487111111111
```

Try using:

```
/^[789]\d{9}$/
```

The `^` denotes start of string.

`Background-image` is also bad. The CSS property does not have capital `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS for label.error from:

```
label.error
{
    position:absolute;
    Background-image:url("../images/unchecked.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    margin-left: .3em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #FFEBE8;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width:210px;
    height:15px;
}
```

to:

```
label.error
{
    clear:both;
    float:right;
    Background-image:url("../images/unchecked.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    margin-left: .3em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #FFEBE8;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width:210px;
    height:15px;
}
```

Comment: but be careful when using padding with a float - IE6 does weird things with it - not that people should be using that browser these days.